# Access wireguard's IP inside WSL2 from Windows 10 Host

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, wireguard

So I have this Ubuntu 20.04 instance running inside WSL2 on a Windows 10 machine.
Inside this Ubuntu instance, I installed & configured Wireguard, a VPN program.

Wireguard has now created the device `wg0` , which is successfully connected to the server, and now has the IP `10.0.0.65`.

How can I successfully `ping 10.0.0.65` from my Windows 10 machine ?

Here is the output of my `wg0.conf`:

```
root@DESKTOP-8KN2S3S:/# cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.65/8
SaveConfig = false
PostUp = iptables -I INPUT -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = 1234567890XXXXXXXX=


[Peer]
#VPN Server
PublicKey = 1234567890XXXXXXXX=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/8
PersistentKeepalive = 25
Endpoint = 1.1.1.1:51820
```

Here is the output of `netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface`:

```
------  ---------------  ---------  ---------  -------------
4294967295                1          0     355280  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
  1420                1    3591066     882662  Work
  1500                1  1706422282   25253612  Wi-Fi
  1500                5          0          0  Ethernet
  1500                5          0          0  Local Area Connection* 1
  1500                5          0          0  Local Area Connection* 10
  1500                1          0     800283  VirtualBox Host-Only Network
  1500                5          0          0  Bluetooth Network Connection 2
  1500                1   10614784     610167  vEthernet (WSL)
```

Comment: Please provide your WIreguard server configuration. We also need the output of `netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface`

Comment: There you go my friend, I edited the question.

Comment: You would need to expand the list of IP Addresses allowed by editing AllowedIPs.  I assume you have a working Wireguard client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer Networking can be a complex beast.

On the WSL machine you can run

```
ip addr
```

This will list the virtual network interfaces (NIC's) you have on your wsl machine. Most likely your the inet address on your **eth0** interface is what WSL uses as default.

On Windows you can ping this ip address from the cmd/powershell cli. You can also verify the network bridge associated between the 2 different kernel's (windows / linux) under:

```
ipconfig
```

Output:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):
    IPv4 Address <some value>
```

Now that you've set up a wireguard interface, you should be able to ping it as long as there is a route to it.

By default all packets are sent via the default gateway that would be the physical ethernet wire attached to your PC or your WiFi interface.

To access the **wg0** interface via ping you must add a *static* route to the network in your windows routing table. You can access this via the **route** command

```
route print
```

Add a Static Route to the Windows Routing Table You can use the following syntax: [How to add a static route in windows](https://tekbloq.com/2018/10/24/how-to-add-a-static-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/)

```
route ADD destination_network MASK subnet_mask gateway_ip metric_cost
```

For example:

```
route add 172.16.121.0  mask 255.255.255.0 10.231.3.1
```

Populate the destination network with your wireguard interface network and mask; the rest with the vEthernet (WSL) interface information. And viola!

You should now have ping working.

**NOTE**: This re-directs packets onto your WSL machine. It is assumed you have routes from the WSL machine to your wg0 interface.

If you want to tunnel your packets through wireguard... You will have to follow all the above steps, and also *configure a wireguard client* on your windows machine.

Comment: This allows a ping, but it wouldn't let the host connect to the server, unless the host was already a member of the same subnet.  If it wasn't then the route wouldn't likely be required.  This isn't criticism towards your answer just an observation.

Comment: Was making a few edits to my wordings. See if the last few lines make sense now.

Comment: Yes; I saw your edit. My comment really is to let the author understand just allowing a ping won't let them connect to the server itself.  However, how to do that, wasn't their question.  Which is the reason my comment wasn't criticism towards your answer.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot guys, really appreciated !

Comment: Awesome. Please do also upvote the answer if you think it helped you out :)