# Access WSL2 distro's VPN network from host

Tags: vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am running an Ubuntu 20 in WSL2, and I am connecting to a VPN network using openfortivpn. Within the distro (from CLI) I can reach the desired remote hosts, but I cannot reach them from Windows.

What should I do in order to reach the remote hosts within the VPN from Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish Windows and WSL to use the VPN, you should enter the VPN from
Windows, not from WSL.

Both will then use the VPN.

Comment: I only want the WSL to use the VPN, but I would like to reach VPN remote hosts from Windows. I was doing the same with VirtualBox in the past using proxy to achieve this. Does WSL have a builtin support for this, or do I have to use proxy?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/a/1707414/8672) was an attempt to create a similar setup. You could try to see if it works for you.