# How to access lan from WSL

Tags: networking, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to access lan (devices connected to the lan) from wsl?

Im using Ubuntu-22.04 distro. I want to connect to a proxy server connected to the lan from wsl. I tried `export http_proxy=http://<IP>:<port>` command but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: This [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1707408/access-wireguards-ip-inside-wsl2-from-windows-10-host) could be helpful.

Comment: Not all programs care about the `http_proxy` env var. (Besides, apparently you shouldn't include `http://` in the value.)